# Accessing C# Class Instances from C++ (Windows Phone 8 Direct3D)

Tags: c#, c++, directx, windows-phone-8, direct3d

Is there any way to access objects which have been instantiated (!) in the XAML/C#-Part of a Windows Phone 8 Direct3D Xaml/C++ App from the native side (C++)?

We tried adding the references but unfortunately had no luck with that.

Comment: @thang WP8 is more limited and not a full .NET/Win32 environment.

Comment: i know but the limitation is in the class library... not the underlying stuff.  you can still build a com dll out of .net class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, first you need to define a Windows Runtime interface in your C++/CX side.

Then you can reference this interface and instantiate a C# object from a class which implements this interface.

Finally you can pass this class instance down to your C++ layer (Windows Runtime component class).

Then you are able from C++ to call methods of that WinRT interface, and your code will run in C#/.NET.